# Change url of a webpage on a local network

Tags: sockets, dns, esp32, micropython

I built a webpage on an ESP32 chip, charged to create an access point allowing my computer to connect in order to access this page.
For the moment I can only access it using the IP of my ESP by typing it in a browser but it can be very bothersome.
I'd like to know if it was possible to change the url of the page using words instead of the ESP's IP.
Maybe I'm missing some technical terms but I didn't find any solution on the internet.

**PS**: I'm using [micropython](https://micropython.org/) with sockets to serve html files from the board:

```py
def handleClient(client_socket):
    headers, data = loadRequest(client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8'))
    # print('[*] Received:\n%s\n%s\n' % (headers, data))
    if headers['method'] == 'GET' and '/connect' == headers['route']:#'/connect' in headers['route']:
        ssid, password, status, code = connect(headers)
        client_socket.sendall(RESPONSE_TEMPLATE % (code, status, {'ssid': ssid, 'password': password}, code))
        return ssid, password
    elif headers['method'] == 'GET' and headers['route'] == '/':
        renderWebPage(client_socket)
    client_socket.close()
    return None, None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are two parts needed to solve your Q:

1. publish a name (using mdns)
2. resolve that name from a client

MicroPython has built-in support for `mdns` since v1.12.
The essential code is to assign a hostname using the below:

```py
wlan.config(dhcp_hostname="prettyname")
```

Note that your client also needs to have mdns support in order to be able to resolve that address. That may/will depend on your client.

a complete sample would be:

```py
import network
wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
if not wlan.isconnected():
    wlan.active(True)
    mac = wlan.config('mac')
    host = "prettyname"
    wlan.config(dhcp_hostname = host)
    wlan.connect('myssid', 'mypassword')
    while not wlan.isconnected():
        pass
        
host = wlan.config('dhcp_hostname')
print('Wifi connected as {}/{}, net={}, gw={}, dns={}'.format(
    host, *wlan.ifconfig()))
```

[Source: MicroPython Forum](https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?t=10979)

Comment: Hey, I've seen something like that on the net but I don't get why you use the STA_IF mode.
Maybe I've been on the wrong track from the begining but if I want to access a webpage from my ESP,  shouldn't I initialize it as AP_IF ?
So I have a new question here : can I use my browser to access a webpage from my ESP when it is in station mode ?
I'm a bit lost here

Comment: Hi Thomas, yes this will work in both STA_IF (client) and AP_IF (Access Point) modes.

Comment: and to understand AP / IF modes please read : https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/esp32/quickref.html#networking to decide if you want the device to connect to a WiFi network, or create it's own WiFi network.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly. The easiest option is enabling [mDNS](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/protocols/mdns.html). This allows hosts in the same local network to resolve the device's name (e.g. `espressif.local`) into its IP. Only works in local network and requires an mDNS client on the computer (Mac, Linux and Windows all tend to have it built in these days).

No idea how to do it in Micropython, though. Give Google a try.